# Suitable Authentication Technique Basic/OAuth1/OAuth2?

Tags: java, android, restful-authentication

Need to develop restful API which is to be used by android app contains login/logout.  which authentication approach should i use Basic/OAuth1/OAuth2?

Comment: `OAuth2` is better

Comment: why Auth2 and why not basic and OAuth1.Could please explain?